# SectionList contentinset not apply when list load

Tags: reactjs, react-native, padding, sticky

I'm use **SectionList** with **stickyheader**

I want to make stickyheader after some top space
so apply paddingTop and contentInset.

[image]

It is Work but when load first time data it display top space like above screen
After minor scrolling space is gone and contentInset start working.

How can i remove space when data is firsttime.

```
<SectionList 
    style={{paddingTop:40}}
    contentInset={{ top: -40 }}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.listHeaderItem}
    ref={ (ref) => {this.myRef=ref}}
    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeaderItem}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    ListFooterComponent={this.footer} 
    bounces={true}
    keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
    sections={this.state.sectionData} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a space at the begging try with... and let me know if  that works

```
style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0}}
```

Comment: No it's not working. I'm use padding top because i want stickyheader after 40 space.

Comment: and stickyheader should be there for always? i mean the list should be on top:0 and with paddingTop 40 for stickyheader for always?

Comment: yes stickyheader should be there for always. yes list should be on top:0 and with paddingTop 40 for stickyheader for always.